# Base URI for spring boot security

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

In old spring (before spring boot) I defined in web.xml

```
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

And in this way security was applied only to URIs under "/rest/" and static resources served from root were unprotected (my html/Angular2 content) . However I cannot find any reference of doing the same in Spring Boot, has anyone already resolved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring boot you can handle such as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDemoApplication {


@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(someFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/rest/*");
    registration.setName("myFilter");
    return registration;
}

@Bean(name = "myFilter")
public Filter myFilter() {
    return new MyFilter();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your web.xml I cannot found anything for the security config.

But as you described, you can config it via the spring security like following to permit the "/" but need authenticated for '/rest/'  path.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class ResourceSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()

            ......
    }
}
```

Here is a good https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ tutorial series for this.